# TLS 1.2 Failure

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I am using Webinspect to scan sites. When going through Webinspect, I get "the client and server cannot communicate because they do not possess a common algorithm".
From the same system, when using Firefox, Chrome, or Edge, I am able to connect.
The sites use PKI for authentication.
Wireshark gives me the following for the failure:

- Client Hello
- Server Hello
- Server: Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
- Client ACK
- Client FIN, ACK
- Client SYN
- Server ACK
- Server FIN, ACK

It then tries to use TLS 1.1, 1.0 (which are disabled) which results in Handshake Failure. Both the server and client agree on the same cipher.
When it is successful, there is no FIN sent, so I am trying to understand why the FIN is being sent with Webinspect and not through Chrome or Firefox.
On a side note, there is another user who has the same setup with Webinspect but on a different system and is able to connect. There is no FIN sent from his capture and it then moves on to the "Certificate, Client Key Exchange, Certificate Verify, Change cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake" Message.

Any information would be helpful, as I am having issues troubleshooting with person who is successful.